# PyScript: Checking if Metamask is installed on the browser with Ethereum

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, metamask, pyscript

I am still learning about the new PyScript in browser. I was wondering if it is possible for me to allow a click button to check if MetMask account is connected. In regular JS we use to write the following:
[image]

However, in PyScript, I am not sure how to get the same functionality. Can anyone help me with a code that demonstrate how to do this in PyScript from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from js import alert, window

if not window.ethereum:
    alert("install metamask")
```

Comment: how could I request the method eth_requestAccounts in this way?

Comment: @Anonymous solved under your question